# VMWare running error

Tags: 21.10, vmware-workstation, vmware-player

I was following this [tutorial](https://itsfoss.com/install-vmware-player-ubuntu-1310/) trying to install VMware Workstation 16.2.3 Player for Linux 64-bit on Ubuntu 21.10 and after trying to launch the program I get the error "before you can run VMWare, several modules must be compiled and loaded in the running kernel"

When running uname -a I get "5.17.0-051700rc7-generic" so the kernal version matches.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9pSD.png)

Comment: Can you use another virtualization (eg. KVM built into Linux) instead of VMware?

Comment: Is there also a reason why you are using a version of Ubuntu that will soon go EoL with kernel that does not come with it?  Mainstream kernels do not build the same way and will miss the headers from being installed or they may not be compatible.